# Segfault error when calling a method through pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a baseclass called gridObject

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

class gridObject
{
public:
    gridObject();
    virtual ~gridObject();

    virtual int get_GridID() = 0;

    virtual int get_x() = 0;
    virtual int get_y() = 0;

    virtual int get_direction() = 0;

    void set_x(int x);
    void set_y(int y);

    void set_direction(unsigned int direction);

protected:
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;

    unsigned int _direction;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

I have a subclass called player

Here's the get_GridID() method in the class file:

```
int player::get_GridID() { return 2; }
```

There's also a grid class that keeps track of all the objects on it via a 2d vector. In the header file, there's that vector:

```
private:
    vector<vector<gridObject*> > _position;
```

Here are the methods for setting and getting an object at a specific position, respectively:

```
void grid::setGridPosition(int x, int y, gridObject* obj) { _position[y][x] = obj; }
gridObject* grid::getGridPosition(int x, int y) { return _position[y][x]; }
```

The problem I'm having is here:

```
int main()
{
    grid * gr = new grid(10, 10);

    player p(0, 0, 100);

    gridObject * go = &p;

    gr->setGridPosition(0, 0, go);

    cout << gr->getGridPosition(0, 0)->get_GridID();

    return 0;
}
```

It crashes at: cout << gr->getGridPosition(0, 0)->get_GridID();

I have included all of the appropriate header files.

EDIT: Here is the constructor for grid and the initialization of _position:

```
grid::grid(int width, int length)
{
    setSize(width, length);
}


void grid::setSize(int width, int length)
{
    setLength(length);
    setWidth(width);
}

void grid::setLength(int val) { _position.resize(val); }

void grid::setWidth(int val)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _position.size() - 1; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < _position.at(i).size() - 1; j++)
           _position.at(i).resize(val);
}
```

Comment: You should try to remove all irrelevant code, and add the relevant code, which is missing. How do you initialize `_position` for example? What do your constructors and destructors fo?

Comment: Especially `getGridPosiion()` and `setGridPosition()`. And note, if you have a fault triggered by a member function, said-member should *always* be among the code slices you post.

Comment: added the constructor and initialization

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide the relevant parts of the code. Furthermore you should try to debug your code and check all the members/variables/pointers etc. you're using. Using a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can also be helpful.

Comment: What's the type of _position? Is it a simple nested vector `std::vector<std::vector<grid_object*> >` ? And why don't you go all the way through the _position vector like `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _position.size(); i++)` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a nested vector. 

Wouldn't that cause an index out of bounds error?

Comment: No, a index is in bounds if it's inside the range of [0; vector.size()-1]. But you actually just initialize the range [0; vector.size()-2].

Answer (score 0):

You're working with vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<gridObject*> > _position;
```

but the way you initialize `_position` is following:

```
_position.resize(length);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _position.size() - 1; i++)
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < _position.at(i).size() - 1; j++)
       _position.at(i).resize(width);
```

Note that the first `resize` constructs `length` objects of type `vector<gridObject*>`. Then you are iterating not through these newly-constructed vectors, but rather their elements (second nested loop), which in this case causes that the line `_position.at(i).resize(width);` is never executed and thus `_position[y][x] = obj` tries to access the invalid memory resulting in **undefined behavior** that you observe as segmentation fault.

Try this instead (in `grid::setSize`):

```
_position.resize(length);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _position.size() - 1; ++i)
    _position[i].resize(width);
```

and also consider using `typedef` for creating an alias for `std::vector<gridObject*>` :)

Comment: I'm getting an error in stl_vector.h:

error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::vector<gridObject*>::value_type {aka gridObject*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Electrk: Hmm, try to explicitly resize it within a loop then. See my edit.

Comment: Still getting a segfault error

    void grid::setSize(int width, int length)
    {
        _position.resize(length);

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _position.size(); i++)
            _position[i].resize(width);
    }

Comment: @Electrk: I don't see any other reason why there would be a segfault (in the code that you have shown us). Try to debug your code step by step and find the line that causes it (try to narrow it down...)

Comment: @Electrk: No. You should try to locate the problem on your own, so that you can either fix it on your own or post is as a question where not much code is necessary.